# rvest html_table() error max(p) returning -Inf

Tags: javascript, html, r, rvest

I'm trying to scrape a table from the web (here https://www.cryptoslam.io/nba-top-shot/marketplace).

I have been researching how to do this and seem to have gotten closest using library `rvest` and the `html_table()` function. In fact I was able to download the "FIFA World Cup Record" table from here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazil_national_football_team using the code

```r
webpage_url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazil_national_football_team"
webpage <- xml2::read_html(webpage_url)
tbls <- html_nodes(webpage, "table")
head(tbls)
tbls_ls <- webpage %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  .[[6]] %>%
  html_table(fill = TRUE)
```

Note that I have the libraries `library(xml2)`, `library(rvest)` loaded. I then am using essentially the same code here:

```r
webpage_url <- "https://www.cryptoslam.io/nba-top-shot/marketplace"
webpage <- xml2::read_html(webpage_url)
tbls <- html_nodes(webpage, "table")
head(tbls)
tbls_ls <- webpage %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  .[[1]] %>%
  html_table(fill = TRUE)
```

but getting the error

```
Error in matrix(NA_character_, nrow = n, ncol = maxp) : 
  invalid 'ncol' value (too large or NA)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In max(p) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
2: In matrix(NA_character_, nrow = n, ncol = maxp) :
  NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
```

I have not been able to find any discussion of this error anywhere else. One thing that is different between the two tables is the existence of a `thead` tag in the second one which won't work. I have quite limited knowledge of html so I may be missing some other important differences between the table implementations.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is with RSelenium:

```r
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest) #requires xml2, no need to load separately 
driver <- rsDriver(browser="chrome", port=4234L, chromever ="87.0.4280.87")
client <- driver[["client"]]
client$navigate(webpage_url)
source <- client$getPageSource()[[1]]
  
read_html(source) %>% 
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  html_table() %>%
  `[[`(1) -> result

head(result)
            Listed  Rank                   Crypto        Set                  Team Play Category   SN# Current Price          Owner
1 NA 5 minutes ago 10324     2020-21 Bradley Beal   Base Set    Washington Wizards       Handles 10691   (10.00 USD)        P1BenEe
2 NA 5 minutes ago  1096     2019-20 Kelly Olynyk The Finals            Miami Heat         Layup   360  (180.00 USD) Top_Shot3point
3 NA 5 minutes ago  3138      2019-20 Alex Caruso   Base Set    Los Angeles Lakers         Block   679     67.00 USD CaptainThunder
4 NA 5 minutes ago  3586  2020-21 Kelly Oubre Jr.   Base Set Golden State Warriors          Dunk  3583      5.00 USD       dddd9999
5 NA 5 minutes ago  3318  2020-21 Bismack Biyombo   Base Set     Charlotte Hornets         Layup  3315      7.00 USD       ectoasty
6 NA 5 minutes ago  4940 2020-21 DeMarcus Cousins   Base Set       Houston Rockets     3 Pointer  4937    (3.00 USD) StoneColdBroke
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! Just in case someone else stumbles upon this, I did not have much luck with the `rsDriver()` function. Many people instead use docker to avoid the headache. Info can be found here <https://rpubs.com/johndharrison/RSelenium-Docker>

Answer (score 0):

That data comes from an API post request returning json. You can issue that request then parse json, returned as list from content, into whatever your desired format is

```
library(httr)

headers = c(
  'user-agent'= 'Mozilla/5.0',
  'content-type'= 'application/json',
  'referer'= 'https://www.cryptoslam.io/',
  'accept-language'= 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8'
)

data = '{"draw":1,"columns":[{"data":null,"name":"","searchable":true,"orderable":false,"search":{"value":"","regex":false}},{"data":null,"name":"TimeStamp","searchable":true,"orderable":true,"search":{"value":"","regex":false}},{"data":null,"name":"","searchable":true,"orderable":false,"search":{"value":"","regex":false}},{"data":null,"name":"Tokens.0.Rank","searchable":true,"orderable":true,"search":{"value":"","regex":false}},{"data":null,"name":"Tokens.Attributes.Name","searchable":true,"orderable":true,"search":{"value":"","regex":false}},{"data":null,"name":"Tokens.Attributes.Set","searchable":true,"orderable":false,"search":{"value":"","regex":false}},{"data":null,"name":"Tokens.Attributes.Team","searchable":true,"orderable":false,"search":{"value":"","regex":false}},{"data":null,"name":"Tokens.Attributes.PlayCategory","searchable":true,"orderable":false,"search":{"value":"","regex":false}},{"data":null,"name":"Tokens.Attributes.SerialNumber","searchable":true,"orderable":true,"search":{"value":"","regex":false}},{"data":null,"name":"CurrentPrice","searchable":true,"orderable":true,"search":{"value":"","regex":false}},{"data":null,"name":"EndingPriceGwei","searchable":true,"orderable":true,"search":{"value":"","regex":false}},{"data":null,"name":"","searchable":true,"orderable":false,"search":{"value":"","regex":false}},{"data":null,"name":"","searchable":true,"orderable":false,"search":{"value":"","regex":false}}],"order":[{"column":1,"dir":"desc"}],"start":0,"length":50,"search":{"value":"","regex":false},"startdate":"","enddate":"","marketplace":"","attributesQuery":{}}'

r <- httr::POST(url = 'https://api2.cryptoslam.io/api/marketplace/NBA Top Shot/search', httr::add_headers(.headers=headers), body = data) %>% content()
```